Shortcuts to Exit Equation Environment
Is there any hotkeys/shortcuts to exit the equation environment in Overleaf since it auto-completes $$ and \(\). I thought tab would do it, but it just creates spaces after you finish the equation: $1=1    $.
Thanks

(Looking through the Overleaf documentation on this issue, it doesn't appear that such a hotkey is available.

If you are a Vim user, you can however enable Vim key bindings and just use <C-o>A as you would in Vim.

I am not familiar with Vim. I just turned off auto-close brackets.
